# Error: Android adb devices unauthorized

Tags: android, adb, unauthorized

**Information:**

- Windows: 10
- Smartphone: Alcatel Pixi 4 5" 5045J (Rooted)
- ADB version: 1.0.32

**Problem:**

The screen to my phone is burned, the touch does not work. I'm trying to use the computer screen to mirror the image but I can not. USB debugging is enabled on the Device but it is still necessary to check the RSA confirmation dialog on the device, which is impossible with the screen being burned.

**Questions**

- Is there any way to mirror the SmartPhone image on the Computer without it being necessary to accept the USB debug connection on the device?
- Is there any way to allow Adb on the device without having to confirm the USB debugging dialog for this?
- Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: The significance of your title is not clear, and I assume it is an error that you are receiving somewhere; you do not mention it in the body of the question. If it is indeed an error, take a look at the many [questions that mention it here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Android+adb+devices+unauthorized).

Comment: My English is not good

Answer (score 1):

you can use **airdroid**  or **google chrome airmirror plugin** for sharing the screen to desktop. 

try this, 

links are below
[airdroid desktop version](https://airdroid-desktop.en.softonic.com/) 
or 
[airmirror google chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/airmirror/macmgoeeggnlnmpiojbcniblabkdjphe)